# Ctrl + Z not undoing on Ubuntu Gnome OS

Tags: ubuntu, shortcut, gnome, hotkeys, ctrl

Recently I've got into some trouble using Ubuntu GNOME OS (16.04), my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut to undo isn't working at all. It normally does work just fine, so I'm guessing I just broke something but couldn't figure out what exactly. Tried to search on Gnome keyboards configuration, no luck though, there aren't any shortcuts set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, also I couldn't find anything on gconf related to that. Others <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> hotkeys are working fine, just as <kbd>Z</kbd> button is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it. Was using an extension that had <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> attached to it, even though the shortcut was turned off it still took over the default hotkey's behaviour.